# Cannot convert URL to Data(contentsOf: URL) in swift5

Tags: swift

I know there are many solutions around related to converting an Image string into data and to set the image in an ImageView. But unfortunately, nothing worked in my case. I have a parsed JSON field which returns an Image as a string. So I'm trying to convert that String as URL and then to get URL data to display the image. But when the error is throwing when I try to get the data from URL like

```
let testImage = Data(contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL)
```

> Error: "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'contentsOf:', expected
>   'dictionary:')"

```
if let url21 = URL(string: brandingLogo) {
do {
        let testImage = Data(contentsOf: url21)

        self.BrandingBarImage.image = UIImage(data: testImage)
   }
   catch
   {
       print("error")
   }
}

**Code for brandingLogo:**

guard let url = URL(string: urlJson) else {return}

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data1, response, error) in

            do {
        let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data1!) as? [String:Any]
                let statusList = parsedData?["data"] as? [String:Any]
                let anotherData = statusList?["data"] as? [String:Any]
           if let players = anotherData?["players"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for logo in players {

          self.brandingLogo = logo["logo_app_branding_bar"] as? String
                print(self.brandingLogo)

        }
```

brandingLogo is parsed from Json and its value is: https://media.socastsrm.com/wordpress/wp-content/blogs.dir/223/files/2018/01/blank-300x95.png

so, I'm assuming that when this 'brandingLogo' is considered as String, it takes only the actual string like : 
https://media.socastsrm.com/wordpress/wp-content/blogs.dir/223/files/2018/01/blank-300x95.png 
And so I'm trying to convert that image string to URL and then to get Data

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The `try` is missing: `let testImage = try Data(contentsOf: url21)`

Comment: yes, tried with 'try' as well..same error at that line

Comment: Is there somewhere a custom type `Data` which hides Foundation `Data`? By the way don't load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf:`. Never do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @vadian . I am new to the development, still in the learning phase... btwn, there is no custom type 'Data' anywhere in the project. can you please suggest any better way to achieve this?

Comment: The usual way to load data from a remote URL is `URLSession` and `URLSessionDataTask`.

Comment: okay..I am now able to get contents from Data and it returns bytes instead of image url. let url21 = URL(string: self.brandingLogo)
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data21 = try? Data(contentsOf: url21!)
            print(data21 as Any)
            //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.BrandingBarImage.image = UIImage(data: data21! as Data)
            }
        } .                     any suggestions @vadian ..thanks